# Do I need another method to use the ColorFactory class?

Tags: java, swing, methods

I just found this really great [`ColorFactory`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/ColorFactory.htm) class that I am using in my first Swing project. It is really cool: I can now pass a named color from my main class, like "crimson" or "mediumaquamarine" for example, to the `createContentPane` `Container` method.

Code:

```
frame.setContentPane(ContentPaneCreator.createContentPane("darkorange"));`
```

Question:

Do I need the `public final void setBackground(Color color, JPanel contentPane)` method at all? Can everything be done inside `createContentPane()` method instead? Thank you for your help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public final class ContentPaneCreator extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static Container createContentPane(String color) {

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

        // awesome txt to Color conversions using the ColorFactory().getColor();
        // written by The Lobo Project
        new ContentPaneCreator().setBackground(
                new ColorFactory().getColor(color), contentPane);

        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        return contentPane;
    }

    public final void setBackground(Color color, JPanel contentPane) {
        contentPane.setBackground(color);
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things may bear closer scrutiny:

- As you plan to extend `JPanel`, supply a `String colorName` via the constructor and store the name in a field for later reference; the panel's `backgroundColor` is a bound property.
- The [static factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), `ColorFactory.getInstance()`, should be re-factored to use the [*initialization-on-demand holder idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom).
- The code, excerpted from the [Lobo Project](http://lobobrowser.org/), may have since been updated.
- The [names](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp) appear to be [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/).

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question - I can't see why (or why you needed to start with, but hay).

Extended answer:

It should be: (if we're looking at the same piece of code)

```
ColorFactory.getInstance().getColor(colorName);
```

Other wise you creating the color map on each instantiation, which is just a waste.

I'm also not sure why you need to extend JPanel, but it's not my code :P

Comment: wow.. just wow. I am extending JPanel because I anticipate future use of it's features.

Comment: Hay, it's your design, if you have a need for it, you have a need for :)