# Extracting named colors out of ColorFactory.java class by the lobo project?

Tags: java, swing

What type of process would I need in a new class to 'read' all of the colors that are in this class below?  I use the class to set colors on components and love it. But the time has come to allow my application to right-click on a panel and change the background color for example.

What would get me started in the correct direction code-wise in continuing to use these colors: [`ColorFactory.java`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/ColorFactory.htm)

I was just starting to think about adding a new method to the class something like:

```
public Map<String, Color> getColorMapValues(){

    return colorMap;
    //
}
```

Comment: Ouch, this class' synchronization policy is plain broken.

Comment: @OlivierCroisier Hi Oliver, I am new to Java, what does that mean?  Thank you. JoJo

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that this class needs no synchronization. Personally, I would make the map immutable, and the color-code-strings should be reparsed every time - it might even be faster than using the map! But even so, a non-blocking map would be fine: so once in a while you parse-and-put the same color twice - not a big concern.

Comment: The singleton initialization scheme is broken. It uses a technique called "double-check locking" that has been proven wrong ages ago. I would simply initialize the singleton at its declaration site : private final ColorFactory INSTANCE = new ColorFactory(); and get rid of all synchronization in the getInstance() method. Also, the color map initialization could be done in the constructor or non-static initialization block.

Comment: Please don't copy LGPL code here; this site uses a different [license](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: See also [Do I need another method to use the ColorFactory class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679985/do-i-need-another-method-to-use-the-colorfactory-class)

Comment: @OlivierCroisier double check locking **was** broken, but is fixed and  encouraged when lazy initialization is required. See http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html, and Effective Java (2nd Edition) Item 71.

Comment: I know, but it requires the instance to be volatile, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have control over the source code in this case, it would be better to refactor the class to meet your needs than using reflection (which is not only expensive, but is prohibited depending on your security policy).

The technique commonly used is the `Holder pattern`. See Joshua Bloch's Effective Java (2nd Edition) Item 71 for more information. We can also avoid synchronization on reads by using a thread-safe, non blocking structure, namely `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`.

```
public class ColorFactory {
    private static class ColorFactoryHolder {
        // creates on instantiation of ColorFactoryHolder
        // synchronization is baked into the JVM, but won't be created until
        // the class is used, see JLS 12.4.1
        static final ColorFactory instance = new ColorMap();
    }
    public static ColorFactory getInstance() { return ColorFactoryHolder.instance; }
    // concurrent hash map - all operations are thread safe
    Map<String,Color> colormap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Color>();
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private ColorFactory() {
        colormap.add("blue",new Color(0,0,255));
        // rest of colors here
    }
    public Color getColor(String spec) {
        if(colormap.containsKey(spec)) return colormap.get(spec);
        // don't synchronize externally - Bloch et al, item 70
        synchronized(lock) { 
            // double check idiom - not broken, as map is thread safe
            if(colormap.containsKey(spec)) return colormap.get(spec);
            Color color = parse(spec); // parse method can be extracted from old code
            colormap.put(spec,color);
            return color;
        }
    }
    private static Color parse(String spec) {
        // parse the color spec here
    }    
}
```

In fact, because the parse operation is likely to be very, very fast (in comparison to the synchronization), we can do away with the synchronization altogether. So we might end up parsing the value multiple times - not really a big problem, since the result will be the same every time. See Bloch et al. Item 69 for more information.

```
public class ColorFactory {
    private static class ColorFactoryHolder {
        // same as above, snipped for brevity
    }
    public static ColorFactory getInstance() { return ColorFactoryHolder.instance; }
    // requires ConcurrentMap reference to get putIfAbsent(K,V) method
    ConcurrentMap<String,Color> colormap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Color>();
    // private final Object lock = new Object(); - removed
    private ColorFactory() {
        colormap.add("blue",new Color(0,0,255));
        // rest of colors here
    }
    public Color getColor(String spec) {
        Color result = colormap.get(spec);
        if(result == null) {         
            result = parse(spec); // may parse multiple times, but still
                                  // cheaper than synchronization
            colormap.putIfAbsent(spec,result);            
        }
        return result
    }
    private static Color parse(String spec) {
        // parse the color spec here
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the color map by reflexion.
I don't guarantee the following code since I don't have my IDE at hand, but this should do the trick :

```
private static Map<String, Color> getColorMap() throws Exception {
    Field colorMapField = ColorFactory.class.getDeclaredField("colorMap");
    colorMapField.setAccessible(true);
    return (Map<String, Color>) colorMapField.get(ColorFactory.getInstance());
}
```

Then you can just query the returned color map to get the Color by name :

```
Map<String, Color> colorMap = getColorMap();
Color yellow = colorMap.get("yellow");
```

If you want to modify the color map, just retrieve it with the method above, put() "any color you like" (yeah, Pink Floyd reference!), then call this method :

```
public void setColorMap(Map<String, Color> colorMap) throws Exception {
    Field colorMapField = ColorFactory.class.getDeclaredField("colorMap");
    colorMapField.setAccessible(true);
    colorMapField.set(ColorFactory.getInstance(), colorMap);
}
```

Be warned that this is quite dangerous with respect to the class' synchronization policy, but it should work provided you don't spam it with multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. So would the correct import here be import java.lang.reflect.Field; ? Quite a few came up but yeah I think I am following this. I will see if I can get something working and I am heading off now to create a right-click action to bring up a menu; that's before I do anything else! ha. =)

Comment: Exactly ! This code uses reflection, therefore you must import some classes from the java.lang.reflect package.

Comment: I also added @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") over the getColorMap().. Eclipse is barking that there is an Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,Color>.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11681949/230513) to JoJo's previous question on this topic.