# Closing a swing application once code is complete

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This is no doubt a simple question for expert 'swingers' but after some research I've not come up with anything.

I have code in this form:

```
    public static void main(Strings[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Symbol Formatter");
    final JButton button = new JButton("Begin");
    final JFileChooser filechoose = new JFileChooser();

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            filechoose.showOpenDialog(frame);
            filename = filechoose.getSelectedFile();

            doSomething(filename);

            button.setEnabled(false);
            frame.setVisible(false); //edit for Andrew Thompson
        }

    });
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(button);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(250, 75);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I want to close the swing application once `doSomething(filename)` is completed. At the moment, the original frame remains where it is and the application only terminates when the frame is closed manually. How can I close once `doSomething(filename)` has run once.

I'm sure this is a simple question and just requires changing `setDefaultCloseOperation` however, the [Jframe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) documentation hasn't helped me much.

Also, is there a way to add a title to the `showOpenDialog`? So that is has something like "**Choose library file**" as the title

Comment: What about just adding `System.exit(0)` at the end of your `actionPerformed` implementation? Also (depending on the circumstances) you might want to use `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` to exit the whole application when the frame is closed (not just to dispose the window).

Comment: upvote for the usage of "swingers"

Comment: OT: See also the standard names cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11681949/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

`frame.dispose()`

Answer (score 1):

Call..

```
frame.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: You've shown yourself to know your stuff, but I'm afraid, in this instance, that's not right, it doesn't terminate the application. It simple hides it.

Comment: Post an SSCCE and I will experiment.

Comment: I added in that method call, where I imagine is correct. Running in Eclipse, the application does not terminate, which becomes a problem for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you change the default close operation to

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Calling `dispose` should terminate the application & exit the JVM.

If that fails, as has been mentioned, call `System.exit(0)` will certainly terminate te JVM

Answer (score 0):

For the file chooser dialog title, see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setDialogTitle%28java.lang.String%29).